# How to create a database for selection of correct letters to form a word (answer) for a quiz type android game?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsCSE.jpg

My game is very similar to this game named "Riddle Me That" but it's in another language. The design part is complete and I've implemented the buttons and all but how should I create the database to implement it in the app? I'm using SQLite to create the database. In a table I've created a question column and answer column. Now since the answer needs to be formed using combination of letters that is to be input by users (please see the link above), I'm really confused on how to make the database. Please help!

Comment: What exactly are you confused about?

Answer (score 0):

If you are confused about the Database there are too much tutorials about it just google it .
But i really don't recommend you to use the databases in such app you can use instead the string resources (res > values > strings.xml) and add a string array for questions and another for answers .
and be sure about the order so that the first item in answers array would be the answer of the first item in the question array and so on.
for example :

res/values/strings.xml

```
<string-array name="questions">
    <item>who are you ?</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="answers">
    <item>Omar</item>
</string-array>
```

and here is the java code to fetch the arrays :

```
    String[] questions;
    String[] answers;
    public void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {   

      //here is how to get the string arrays from the resources to fetch them as you like
      questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
      answers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.answers);


    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide me a link or a tutorial that helps to elaborate your answer more clearly?

Comment: this is from the Android developer site:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: and this one from the tutoriaslPoint website : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm